# String function in syscall.Errno

Tags: go

Reading through the 7.8 section of "The Go Programming Language" I spotted following code:

```
var err error = syscall.Errno(2)
fmt.Println(err.Error()) // "no such file or directory"
fmt.Println(err)         // "no such file or directory"
```

I understand the first and second line. `error` interface is saitisfied by `syscall.Errno`, thus `Error()` function returning `string` is available.

I don't understand third one. Going through `syscall`'s [sources](https://golang.org/src/syscall/syscall_unix.go?s=2735:2753#L104) I can't find any place where `syscall.Errno` satisfies `stringer` interface - `String()` function is not defined.

Why third one prints string representation of `sysscall.Errno`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is found in the `fmt` documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Printing):

> If the format (which is implicitly %v for Println etc.) is valid for a string (%s %q %v %x %X), the following two rules apply:
>
> 4. If an operand implements the error interface, the Error method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).
> 5. If an operand implements method String() string, that method will be invoked to convert the object to a string, which will then be formatted as required by the verb (if any).

So actually, for any value that supports both, the `String()` method is never called at all, since the `error` interface takes precidence over the `Stringer` interface.  You can test this with a program like [this one](https://play.golang.org/p/EbZpJN_iJVS):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type foo string

func (f foo) String() string {
    return "string"
}

func (f foo) Error() string {
    return "error"
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo(""))
}
```

Output:

```
error
```